What is the best way to manage trust-, keystores in a microservice architecture?
We have quite a few microservices and monolith applications which are calling each other and other external services and its getting harder and harder to manage keystores and truststores.
The problems we are experiencing:

Currently we are storing information about them in a spreadsheet and replacing them by hand if they expire so there is a LOT of human errors that can happen and they are happening too. For example the management team forgets to update their expiry or even completely forgets to create a new entry for a  new microservice.
There are a lot of stores that multiple apps use and sometimes they are stored as a serialized DB record, sometimes its just a file that the app can use. Updating these can take a lot of time which results in a lot of downtime.
Some of our applications have multiple trust/keystores with 1 certificate inside which is quite idiotic i know but this is what our predecessors left for us. This makes managing and keeping track of keystores even harder.

My questions are:
What are the best practices to manage these keystores?
Are there tools that can make these tasks easier? Is it possible to update these keystores automatically with such tools when the keystores are stored in different format for each app?
What are your recommendations to make our life easier?
I tried looking for keystore management tools on google but every tool was missing some features.
